# How a several dispatch_async to execute sequentially?

Tags: ios, ios7, grand-central-dispatch

I have 2 methods:

```
-(void)clear
{
  // some code

  dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), 
        ^{
              // async_block_1

         });     
}

-(void)download
{
  // some code

  dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), 
        ^{
              // async_block_2

         });     
}
```

And I need call'em in 3rd method:

```
-(void)relosd
{
   [self clear];
   [self download];
}
```

How I can guaranted perform first async_block_1 then async_block_2?

Obvious that the following code does not guarantee this:

```
-(void)reload
{
    dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), 
       ^{
           [self clear];
           [self download];
       });
}
```

Comment: Could you do this as a "`NSOperationQueue`" thing with ["`setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:) set to 1?

Comment: Michael, yes, I can. But why? CGD also can do it with serial queue. But I need parallel working, that will sinchronized sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

GCD queue can be create to run as a [serial queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6).

Just create your own queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.my.download", NULL);
```

You can do this `.m` part where you functie are declared something like:

```
dispatch_queue_t getDownloadQueue() {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static dispatch_queue_t ruleQueue;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        ruleQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.my.download", NULL);
    });

    return ruleQueue;
}
```

Just place this code outside of your `@implementation`, after which you can just do something like:

```
-(void)clear {
  // some code
  dispatch_async( getDownloadQueue(), ^{
    // async_block_1
  });     
}

-(void)download {
  // some code

  dispatch_async(getDownloadQueue(), ^{
    // async_block_2
  });     
}
```

If you only need the queue in one instance of you class then use a property, this example will create a queue which you can use throughout your app and makes sure that they are executed in order.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably after what rckoenes is suggesting but your other options are.

- Use `NSOperationQueue` and set dependencies
- Use `NSOperationQueue` and set maxConcurrentOperationCount
- Use `dispatch_barrier_async` instead of `dispatch_async`